# Python setup.py points to . as opposed to the directory specified in setup.py?

Tags: python, setup.py

This is my current project setup:

```
.
├── README.md
├── build
│   ├── bdist.macosx-10.8-intel
│   └── lib
├── dist
│   └── giordano-0.1-py2.7.egg
├── giordano.egg-info
│   ├── PKG-INFO
│   ├── SOURCES.txt
│   ├── dependency_links.txt
│   ├── not-zip-safe
│   └── top_level.txt
├── requirements.txt
├── setup.py
├── src
│   ├── giordano
│   └── spider
├── test.txt
└── venv
    ├── bin
    ├── include
    ├── lib
    └── share
```

And this is my setup file:

```
from setuptools import setup

setup(name='giordano',
  version='0.1',
  packages=['giordano'],
  package_dir={'giordano': 'src/giordano'},
  zip_safe=False)
```

When I do `python setup.py install`, I am able to `import giordano` in my code without problems.

However, when I am doing `python setup.py develop`, this is the console output:

```
[venv] fixSetup$ python setup.py develop
running develop
running egg_info
writing giordano.egg-info/PKG-INFO
writing top-level names to giordano.egg-info/top_level.txt
writing dependency_links to giordano.egg-info/dependency_links.txt
reading manifest file 'giordano.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
writing manifest file 'giordano.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
running build_ext
Creating /Users/blah/Dropbox/projects/Giordano/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/giordano.egg-link (link to .)
Removing giordano 0.1 from easy-install.pth file
Adding giordano 0.1 to easy-install.pth file

Installed /Users/blah/Dropbox/projects/Giordano
Processing dependencies for giordano==0.1
Finished processing dependencies for giordano==0.1
```

I noticed that the egg is linked to `.` as opposed to `src/giordano`. I can no longer `import giordano` in my code.

Any ideas why develop is not respecting `package_dir`?

Answer (score 0):

Try with 'giordano': 'src'.  distutils/distribute looks for the module or package name in the directory you specify; in the code you pasted, the value is one directory too deep.

Comment: I have `package_dir={'giordano': 'src'}` but I still can't import giordano.

Comment: Can you give a link to the code, or paste the complete traceback?

Comment: I saw this working in another project: package_dir={'': 'src'}